# Smart way to find the corresponding nullable type?

Tags: c#, reflection, types, nullable

How could I avoid this dictionary (or create it dynamically)?

```
Dictionary<Type,Type> CorrespondingNullableType = new Dictionary<Type, Type>
{
    { typeof(bool),    typeof(bool?) },
    { typeof(byte),    typeof(byte?) },
    { typeof(sbyte),   typeof(sbyte?) },
    { typeof(char),    typeof(char?) },
    { typeof(decimal), typeof(decimal?) },
    { typeof(double),  typeof(double?) },
    { typeof(float),   typeof(float?) },
    { typeof(int),     typeof(int?) },
    { typeof(uint),    typeof(uint?) },
    { typeof(long),    typeof(long?) },
    { typeof(ulong),   typeof(ulong?) },
    { typeof(short),   typeof(short?) },
    { typeof(ushort),  typeof(ushort?) },
    { typeof(Guid),    typeof(Guid?) },
};
```

Comment: Could you please explain your reason for having such a dictionary? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to do something like:

```
Type structType = typeof(int);    // or whatever type you need
Type nullableType = typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(structType);
```

To get the corresponding `Nullable<T>` for a given T (in this example, `int`)

Answer (score 2):

`type?` is just syntactic sugar for `Nullable<type>`

Knowing this, you can then do something like this:

```
public Type GetNullableType(Type t) => typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(t);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple generics method:

```
public Type GetNullable<T>() where T : struct
{
  return typeof(Nullable<T>);
}
```

This should return the nullable type for any type you pass in.

Comment: This was my first idea, but I do not have the `T` at compile time but just an instance of `System.Type`.

Comment: You do not need T at compile time - thats the wonder of generics.